# MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra library works in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, mathnet-numerics

Does anybody have problems with certain extension methods in the namespace using *MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra*; *Math.NET Numerics dll 4.8.1* when using this DLL with *Visual Studio Professional 2019 NET framework ver 4.8.03752*?

The reason I ask is that certain methods seem to work and others don't (but don't give any runtime errors or exceptions, they just don't seem to do anything).

I could post code but I'm not sure if it's me or if it's the version.  I'm not familiar that much with MathNet's Matrix class, but I think I have gotten the hang of it.  For example I can read elements from within a MathNet Matrix, can zero a column or row, can initialize the Matrix, but I can't multiply a Matrix with a scalar, and I can't seem to add them, nor take the Cholesky decomposition, these methods don't do anything, not even thown any exception, they just don't work it seems.

Is it me or is it MathNet?  Their documentation implies perhaps the version is not really supposed to work with VS19 but an earlier VS version?

C# Windows 10 VS 2019, tried various tests in console mode.  If anybody asks I can post the code here.  Just trying to find out if anybody else has problems in this environment.

Update:  I guess my broader question is that if it's possible to use extension methods and/or a library and not have any compile and runtime exceptions?  For example, I notice while IntelliSense picks up the methods and allows me to peek at the definition, I'm not sure they are running, is this possible?  Also certain tutorial FAQ docs on the MathNet website show functions that IntelliSense doesn't show in the latest library (maybe they were dropped).

An example of code that 'works' (but .Inverse doesn't work, nor any of the other sophisticated Matrix extensions)

```
    *void ShowMatrixElements(Matrix<double> mm, int RowMax, int ColMax)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColMax; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < RowMax; i++)
            {
                double d_ = mm[i,j];
                Debug.WriteLine("the value of Matrix is at Row {0}, Col {1}, {2:0.00}", i,j, mm[i,j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

// works fine to show m,n elements in Matrix after mm is initialized, for example: Matrix m1 = Matrix.Build.Random(2, 2); // create a dense matrix with 2 rows and 2 columns of random numbers   this.ShowMatrixElements(m1,2,2); //works to show stuff*

Comment: Supported version isn't related to Visual Studio at all, it's related to target .NET framework version of your app. According their [github](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics) their support .Net Framework 4.0 or higher  and .Net Standard 1.3 or higher. You have to ensure that you are using the correct version of library from nuget package

Comment: I am using .NET Core 2.1 (Console mode) from what I can tell.  I will edit my original question to ask some more questions.  Too bad I can't use the MathNet.Numerics (4.8.1) library for matrixes, as it looks just like what I need.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: BTW, I don't mind if I can't use their library, as I will write my own functions.  I just want to confirm that before I go off and write my own and maybe waste time.  As I only code for fun, this phenomena of "compile library OK from GitHub, have it show up in IntelliSense, some of the functions work but not all work" is something I'm not familiar with, but maybe it's common.  I've only just now gotten back into coding after several years hiatus.  I only just learned about GitHub and importing libraries a few says ago; in past I installed libraries in a certain MSFT folder in Program Files.